# Reputation for awarding bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I've read about situations where the user who have started a bounty didn't award it to any of the answers despite several deserving ones.

I'm just curious whether rewarding a small reputation (2 or 5) would encourage such users to award the bounty than leaving it to expire, in a similar way the OP gets awarded 2 reps for accepting an answer.

Comment: I see 3 downvotes in 3 minutes, but 0 comments on why the question is down-voted. Wonderful community :)

Comment: Downvotes here on Meta in a context like this usually mean "I disagree with the idea". Don't worry about them. They do not cost you any reputation.

Comment: I like this idea for the simple fact that it encourages good behavior.There have been a couple instances where I was awarded the automatic half bounty and then later (after the grace period) the OP accepted my answer. Encouraging the OP to do that sooner would be welcomed.

Comment: I appreciate your response @Pekka웃 and I think I should make it clear that its not about losing the reputation but such downvotes will repel other users from viewing the question thinking its of low quality. Moreover, I believe if users disagree with the idea, they should comment their views and opinion for a healthy discussion than a simple downvote.

Comment: I disagree with this idea, I don't expect it to have the intended effect.

Comment: Meta voting generally isn't about low quality vs. high quality like it is on the main site - it's generally "I agree" or "I disagree." I upvoted this because I agree with the idea, not as a commentary either way on the question quality.

Comment: A bounty is nothing more than an advertisement paid for by imaginary internet points. Its purpose is to draw attention to the question and it's answers, potentially resulting in new answers or existing answers being improved. By the time it's time to award the bounty, the question and it's answers have already benefited from this additional attention. Instead of more rep, why not instead just look at the messaging/notifications to see if they need to be improved to prevent people from forgetting about a bounty they've sponsored. Earning 2 rep won't prevent you from forgetting.

Comment: In my experience, rather a lot of users either award the bounty or mark the answer and let the bounty expire.  But not both.  Presumably they think that a single "it is right" mark is enough.  So the proposal has some merit, but a very practical problem is that this feature is undiscoverable.  Only the people that are in the habit of marking the answer will learn about it, but those are not the ones you need to encourage.

Comment: @Gibin the meta users know that score != Quality here, so there is no real less visibility for your question I would say. And while having someone comment is nice... There should be an easy way to gauge how much backing from the community your proposal gets. The votes do that (check the tag wiki for feature-requests. It even calls it out explicitly)

Answer (score 5):

I've offered a decent amount of bounties before, and in large, I either didn't manually award it because:

- I didn't feel that any of the questions *deserved* the bounty, and they were also disqualified from automatically receiving half, or
- **I just plain ol' forgot about them.**

I don't see much reason to award reputation for a bounty, since the point of a bounty is for you to give up your reputation in exchange for the possibility of an answer.

Comment: If bounties are meant to be an incentive for answering question, those bounties not awarded (or just half awarded) reduce that incentive for other questions with bounties.

Comment: @picciano: But bounties only don't get awarded if no answer was given that was worth awarding one to. Remember: the system will automatically award a bounty based on community voting if the OP doesn't. And if nobody posted an answer that the community felt was worthy of the bounty, well, there's nothing much to be done about that.

Comment: The way I see it @picciano, the incentive has already been offered - the *potential* to get awarded with a bounty.  Unless their question manages to qualify for half of the reward, there's no tacit guarantee that any answerer will actually win the bounty.  From that angle the bounty would have served its purpose by getting more people to look at an answer the question.