# The purpose of losing reputation when using a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

So I discovered it today "offer X of my own reputation for an answer to this question", while it is not sure to be answered.
What is the interest of this policy? Besides having less reputations means having less probability of views for next questions that are not bounties, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty < may answer most of your question

Comment: How would you limite it otherwise? If the bounty costed you nothing, wouldn't ALL questions have bounties?

Comment: @Patrice, simply by limiting the numbers of questions you can transform as bounty during a specific period. That is how I would limite it. So it still does not answer well my question, but thank you to try.

Comment: Well, [here's an uber-Meta dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/175248).  This has more background into the bounty system.

Comment: *"Besides having less reputations means having less probability of views for next questions that are not bounties, right?"* No, not at all. Reputation doesn't affect how many views your question gets. That is entirely based on the title and first n characters of your question until it starts getting voted on.

Comment: @Makoto it answers kinda well, but this system seems to be only for experts, it does not depend of your efforts of research actually, and when you are an expert you need less help or it is on very hard subject, so are bounty only for hard issues?

Comment: Bounties are for people who feel the need to spend points to "thank" someone for an answer, or to get their question looked at by more people. It's there so that people will do that rather than other more problematic actions toward the same goal.

Comment: @Makoto it still applies but when you are not under 70, and that is very easy with only one bounty to be under it. So you are penalized.

Comment: @Avywam wait so your question is 'why is it this way'. I answer it then you go 'but if the system worked this way instead, your point is wrong'. Are you aware this ISN'T the way it works currently? There is no limit to bounties, so you pay for them, it self regulates. If you want to make the system a 'limited bounties/time period', then make that a feature request...

Comment: Downvotes have absolutely nothing to do with being nice.  It's people's judgement of the post; on meta, that can include disagreement with the premise and/or feature request.  Note that you didn't even lose any rep for the downvotes; I'm not sure how much nicer it can be, while still denoting that the question has no merit.

Comment: @fbueckert that is not a matter of losing rep I did notice. So, you wanna argue about merit? look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366915/reputation-for-awarding-bounty), "Meta voting generally isn't about low quality vs. high quality like it is on the main site - it's generally "I agree" or "I disagree." I upvoted this because I agree with the idea, not as a commentary either way on the question quality." -5 or -7 when I just asked "What is the interest of this policy"  so disagree of what? So by talking about merit you are off track of the purpose of meta it seems.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me.  But, regardless, you [**can** have poor questions on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208/meta-does-in-fact-have-low-quality-questions).  People can be voting for the same reasons as main, such as no research, or just straight up not useful, or they can be voting for Meta reasons, as I outlined.  Meta questions still have to have merit to be good questions.

Comment: @fbueckert I think that is you who do not understand: "They're poorly researched" I searched in the bounty doc and meta: no question about it, so searching what in empty? "not clear" --> "What is the interest of this policy" is very clear. "yes, voting on meta is a bit more complex than on more traditional sites" surprise! Then you do not find it interesting. Normal people just ignore it usually, here you're kinda special, just an opinion like others who downvote isn't it.

Comment: At this point, it seems you're deliberately looking for a fight.  Might I suggest stepping away, taking a breath, and coming back once you're in a calmer state of mind?  I get that people disagreeing with you is frustrating, but no one is attacking you.  You're not doing yourself any favors by continuing in an agitated state of mind.

Comment: I definitely echo what fbueckert's saying here, Avy... Where was I insulting, mean, demeaning to you? In one comment you call me 'big headed', you insinuate I didn't answer your question (to which I apologized, using rhetorical questions may not have been ideal). You then call me annoying, say I don't listen. Can you look in my comments and point me to where I have been mean, insulting, derogatory? As said above: yes it's frustrating when people don't agree with you. No one was doing it in a disrespectful manner, so please be respectful too :).

Comment: Besides I would like to delete this topic because downvotes means what it means, ppl won't see it. Guess what? I cannot delete because the downvoters upvoted the answer, so ppl did their choice... I would like to stop to repeat the same things because commentators repeat the same things, and yep that is annoying to repeat and repeat and repeat.

Answer (score 8):

The point is to make featured questions scarce.

If bounties weren’t limited by cost, there would be too many featured questions at once, and the concept would be meaningless.

Also, without a cost of would be hard to set an appropriate reward. Some bounties are worth 50 points, other bounties are worth 500 points. Without a cost for the one setting the bounty, how would you differentiate between those? Or would all bounties be worth the same?

This is the best solution we came up with so far. If you have a better solution, propose it. But better think it through and be prepared for a very thorough examination of your proposal.

Comment: I get what you mean by there: too many members to ask at once, I have not the pretention to managed a website as it is did here so do not expect a better solution from me, but the costs is crazy high no?

Comment: @AvyWam so you've spent 40+ hours researching your question before posting... then 20 more hours before being able to post bounty... and you consider spending 25 more minutes to edit 25 posts for 50 rep points "crazy cost"? (that's in case person is not able to find *any answerable* questions at all when anything even "why `0. - 5` is -5" got 77 upvotes for answer recently)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you should keep calm and let me ask question I want to ask if I want to. I already talked about the limits of the system from my point of view, if you do not agree I really don't care you know. Besides it does not matter to spent 40+ hours researching before posting, the principal is the topic is not already present or does not answer the problem and that your clear in how you introduce the issues. Well the reactions to just ask gives very weird reactions, honestly I laughed, that is as if I declare God does not exists, such a blaspheme to ask or dare to think something else.

Comment: @AvyWam: "*you should keep calm and let me ask question I want to ask if I want to.*" You asked your question, you got an answer. You simply didn't *like* the answer. That's not on anybody but yourself.